# How do I stop the logging of a function call in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

Out of curiosity I right-clicked on a Javascript function (nested in a highly-called jQuery method) in my Firebug console and selected "Log calls to ".  Now I cannot run this page, or anything on this site that calls this function, without having hundreds and thousands of function calls logged to my console.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to turn off the logging for this specific call.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the *Script* tab on the right hand side of the screen you have a *Breakpoints* sub-tab which contains both *logged functions* and *breakpoints*. Click the red **X** beside a *logged function* to remove it.

[image]